# Calling one vb script to another Vb script file wont run in task scheduler

Tags: vbscript, call, scheduled-tasks

Hello everyone ,
         I am trying to run vb script file in schedule task, it works fine when i set run as administrator privileges in schedule task. But when I am trying to call the second script, it runs only first script, the second script wont run.
       Also i tried to run it through a batch file, it only runs the first script, second script not getting a call. The following code is the first script.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "TestScript.vbs"
```

Not working when i run through scheduler task.

Could anyone make a reply.
Your solution could be appreciated here..

Comment: Specify the complete path and turn off on error resume next to get error number.

Comment: You could also try removing `Wscript.` from the CreateObject() code, as it is not necessary. Is this a 64 bit system? Have you checked the vbscript info section where it details scheduled tasks?

Comment: yes my machine is 64 bit windows 2008 server,I fixed my scheduling task issue ,now am receiving an error "Activex component cant create obj" ,why i am receiving this error?

Comment: here my sample code 
Dim Mysite 
   Set MySite = CreateObject("CuteFTPPro.TEConnection")

   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   MySite.Protocol = "FTP"
   MySite.Host = "www.domainname.com"
   MySite.Login = "xxxxx"
   MySite.Password = "xxx"
   MySite.UseProxy = "BOTH"  
   MySite.Connect

   MySite.UploadAsync "C:\sampletest\abc.flv"
  MySite.RemoteFolder = "/test/abc.flv
     MySite.Disconnect
   MySite.Close

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path to `TestScript.vbs`. When scripts are run from Scheduler, the current directory is usually the Windows system folder, *not* the folder your script is being run from.

Alternatively, you can set the current directory before calling your script.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.CurrentDirectory = "c:\scripts"
objShell.Run "TestScript.vbs"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I already given the full path itself i missed to mention that.Also i tried using current directory still scheduler not running the second script.

Comment: Try explicitly running the script with `wscript.exe` then. It shouldn't be needed but it will rule out any issues with file associations. `objShell.Run "wscript.exe c:\TestScript.vbs"`. Also, for testing purposes, put your script in ``c:\`` or some other path without spaces.

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply,i fixed my scheduler task error myself,by choosing Run only when user is logged in General tab ,also choose run in highest privileges.Its works fine in scheduler.

Actually am trying to do file transfer to my back up server, 

Unfortunately am receiving an error "Active component cant create obj",by clicking manually i don't receive this error when i am trying in scheduler am receiving this error.

Comment: To keep things on topic, I would post your solution as an answer and then accept your own answer. Then, ask a new question addressing the "ActiveX component" error that you're receiving.